# How to loop through DateTable and concatenate column values with comma separator on condition

Tags: c#, .net

```
  ViewID   FilterType     filtervalue
    1        COMPANY        ONS 
    1        COMPANY        TEK 
    1        CUSTOMERID     178822 
    1        MANAGERID      05082807 
    1        SITEID         00525 
    1        SITEID         00720
```

I need to join values of the `filtervalue` column if values in the `FilterType  column` are same with comma separated e.g. `company in('ONS','TEK')`

Comment: Is the table sorted by FilterType?

Comment: No its not sorted basically i would like to something abstract it could be a funtion where i can check if column == "COMPANY" then join corresponding values from filter_value with comma separated and this process for each filter type and build a dynamic where clause string

Comment: And do you want to update the table or just get the info to use elsewhere?

Comment: nope i would just use the values to build a string such as company in ('ONS','TEK') and use it on another table in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group them by `FilterType` column value then (for each group) select `filtervalue` column value and extract distinct values:

```
var groupColumn = table.Columns["FilterType"];
var valueColumn = table.Columns["filtervalue"];

foreach (var group in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(x => x[groupColumn]))
{
    var values = group
        .Select(x => String.Format("'{0}'", x[valueColumn]))
        .Distinct();

    // This is value you need for one group (by FilterType)    
    string text = String.Format("{0} IN ({1})",
        group.Key, String.Join(",", values));
}
```

For data in your example if you print `text` to console you'll get:

```
COMPANY IN ('ONS','TEK')
CUSTOMERID IN ('178822') 
MANAGERID  IN ('05082807')
SITEID IN ('00525', '00720')
```

Comment: Change to simple quote if he wants to use it in a where clause

Comment: @user3193626 it's LINQ, just don't forget to include proper namespace (System.Linq). Plue, you're right!

Comment: Thanks a lot Adriano it worked well

Comment: Filter type who has multiple values quotes are coming as ('ONS,TEK') how can it be dones as ('ONS','TEK')

Comment: @user3193626 fixed example, had to add quotes on Select() instead of in Join()

Answer (score 0):

```
public string getFiltervalue(string filterType, DataTable dt)
{
    HashSet<string> values = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
         if(row["FilterType"].ToString().Equals(filterType))
         {
             values.Add("'" + row["FilterType"].ToString() + "'");
         }
    }

    String[] array = new String[values.Count];
    values.CopyTo(array);

    return filterType + " in (" + String.Join(",", array) + ")";
}
```

Comment: getting error 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My bad, thought HashSet add a ToArray() method. I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks plue i tried and its working

Answer (score 0):

Using `LINQ`, what is obvious is that you have to group your query result by `FilterType` and then with a simple `Select` you can get way you want. But comma separating `FilterValue`s is a little tricky but can easily be achieved with `string.join()`. Here is your query with sample data :

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>() 
{
    new Record() { ViewId = 1, FilterType = "COMPANY", FilterValue = "ONS" },
    new Record() { ViewId = 1, FilterType = "COMPANY", FilterValue = "TEK"}, 
    new Record() { ViewId = 1, FilterType = "CUSTOMERID", FilterValue = "178822"}, 
    new Record() { ViewId = 1, FilterType = "MANAGERID", FilterValue = "05082807"}, 
    new Record() { ViewId = 1, FilterType = "SITEID", FilterValue = "00525" },
    new Record() { ViewId = 1, FilterType = "SITEID", FilterValue = "00720" }
};

var result = records.GroupBy(rec => rec.FilterType)
                    .Select(g =>
                                new
                                {
                                    g.Key,
                                    Values = string.Join(",", g.Select(r => r.FilterValue).ToArray())
                                });
```

Comment: Hmmm why to add leading comma just to remove it with TrimStart()? String.Join works pretty well for this stuff (and what he finally needs is just a list of strings so you can do a second Select())

Comment: getting error 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Adriano, Tnx very much, didn't notice the `join` functionality at all, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user3193626, add `using System.Linq;`